# Crackling/Popping sound when shutdown (Lenovo Y410P)

Tags: sound, drivers

I just recently updated from using Luna to Freya (I basically ereased my drive and went with a fresh install from 0), and I have been getting this popping sound when I shut down my laptop (Lenovo Y410P). This had also happened to me before back when I used Luna, but I was able to fix it doing some google searching (I believe this is the solution I used https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers), but this doesn't seem to work on this new kernel.

I've been trying to find a solution on my own to no success; I'm a very superfluous Linux user so I would really appreciate some help here. Any information needed that can be of help I will provide as fast as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this from the hard drive or speakers?

Comment: Its a popping sound from the speakers when I turn off the laptop.

Comment: Can you try upgrading the kernel to 4.4.This solved many hardware issues for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `options snd-hda-intel model=,generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf`.

Source: [Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184818#p1471463).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5821)

Comment: @r3bl The essential part of the answer is already included as is. You may change the formatting of answer to plain text followed by reference link but no extra info will be added. (You can add a cached link such as https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0fKcIHxRaDIJ:https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php%3Fid%3D184818#p1471463 , though. )

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a y410p running Linux Mint 18.1. I added the line as stated above `options snd-hda-intel model=,generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and then rebooted and this solved the issue.